# git merge - merging two branches with different pointers

Tags: git, merge

I'm trying to get a handle of the merge functionality in git. I've made a simple example to play with and am testing, but I'm unable to achieve the desired results. I begin with the following very simple file

```
# calc.py
def add():
    pass

def substract():
    pass
```

I then `git init`, `git add .` and `git commit -a -m "Initial commit"`. This is now my master. I branch off it to create two branches `multiply` and `divide`. I `git checkout divide` and perform some work so that my file in the `divide` branch looks like.

```
# calc.py
def add():
    pass

def substract():
    pass

def divide(x, y):
    return x / y
```

I then I :

```
git checkout master
git merge divide
git branch -d divide
```

This is followed by doing some work on the `multiply` branch which has been branched off from the initial commit and doesn't have the `divide` branch changes added to it. Nevertheless, I add a multiply function so that on my `multiply` branch my file resembles:

```
# calc.py
def add():
    pass

def substract():
    pass

def multiply(x, y):
    return x * y
```

I then want to merge everything together into `master`, so I:

```
git checkout master
git merge multiply
```

but this results in:

```
Auto-merging calc.py
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in calc.py
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

so that the file resembles:

```
# calc.py

def add():
    pass

def substract():
    pass

<<<<<<< HEAD
def divide(x, y):
    return x / y
=======
def mulitply(x, y):
    return x * y
>>>>>>> mulitply
```

According to the git [merging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging#_basic_merging) documentation this is the expected behaviour. I know that I can simply remove the added annotation and `commit`.

Is there anyway to merge these examples without having to manually intervene? I was thinking of using the `--strategy` flag but I can't succussfully automatically merge the files after master has been changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're experiencing a Git merge conflict that requires human intervention.

That is, Git has encountered a scenario that it understandably cannot auto-merge. Does it keep both sets of changes? If not, does it keep the changes from `divide` or from `multiply`? If it is to keep both sets of changes, does Git put the `divide` changes above or below the `multiply` changes? Human intervention is necessary to answer these.

[Git merge strategies](https://git-scm.com/docs/merge-strategies) cannot resolve the conflict in a way that honours both change sets. What merge strategies can do is specify how to handle whitespace and file renames, instruct Git to merge more than two heads, and/or ensure that one side always wins in case of conflict. Merge strategies cannot resolve conflicts in a way that honours two conflicting change sets.